# What do i put in URL Callback on twitter oAuth2.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oauth

I am creating a twitter bot in Visual Studio using C# to get some hands on practice in. I have written all the code necessary but I am now stuck at the permissions section as I am doing this within VS so I don't have an official domain URL to enter. I have tried localhost but it doesn't. Hoping someone can offer some advice :)

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ2Mb.png)

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzKf9.png)

[Twitter Dev Authentication Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yYEu.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example] and describe in detail any issues you are having.  Links to tutorials or documentation you are following are also helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the callback url to localhost.

Use this: https://tolocalhost.com/

Comment: I tired doing this, it still came up with the exception error. Any other methods ?

Comment: @garbanz0: it would help if you intell us the exception error

Comment: I posted the error and the auth page from twitter dev